# Can TLV theoretically be used for browsers?

Tags: data-structures, data, web, information-presentation

Compared with HTML (Hypertext Markup Language), TLV (Tag-Length-Value) also can be used for a data representation. If TLV is designed smart enough, it can represent hierarchies and trees with no problem.

Unlike XML or HTML which are human readable, TLV is not. Because it is showing the tags with numbers than text. On the other side, TLV is not language dependent (human languages such as English, German, Chinese). Now, my question is that regardless of marketing challenges,

- Can TLV theoretically be used for browsers to render a website?
- If yes, will it be faster for rendering the website in the browser as the length is knowing with a minimal effort?
- Is there any reason to prevent people using TLV for website rendering?

Comment: What do you mean with "TLV is not language dependent"?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, I mean that it does not depend on English, German, French, etc. I mean human languages not computer languages.

Comment: HTML is also (human) language independent. There are no French or Chinese HTML tags, not even if the content of the web page is in one of those languages. Representing the content of websites as tags in TLV will not be practically possible.

Comment: using a TLV based DOM serialization is not *impossible*,it's just that browsers only natively support serialization via HTML/XHTML. Of course you could write a JavaScript polyfill to support this format!

Answer (score 1):

> Can TLV theoretically be used for browsers to render a website?

Theoretically, yes.  You could even write a program to mechanistically convert HTML to your TLV format, and as a proof-of-principle, write another program to convert it back at the client end.

> If yes, will it be faster for rendering the website in the browser as the length is knowing with a minimal effort?

The effect would be negligible.  Parsing structured text is trivial for a modern computer.  Executing JavaScript and rendering images and video is the difficult bit.

You didn't mention JavaScript in your question, but that's another text-based standard.  While you could wrap it into TLV, it still leaves you with a big block of text to parse.

> Is there any reason to prevent people using TLV for website rendering?

HTML is human-readable, and hence human-editable.  HTML is naturally structured; you can nest things inside other things as deep you wish.

TLV is binary, so you would need to create an new editor for it.  It isn't naturally structured, so you're going to need a lot of "begin" and "end" tags to simulate the structure, as well as lots of optional tags to replicate the optional parameters that many HTML tags have.

But the main reason is that we have a perfectly good (well, at least adequate) standard, which everybody has already implemented.  Nobody really wants a new and totally incompatible one.